# sequence to vector LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, seq2seq

1. I have 10 sequence of numerical data which is to be used as input to LSTM.
2. And these sequences are mapped to a vector with 2 values.
3. sequences are of equal length.

Please note. Based on the sequence I want to predict the 2 vector values.

How can I proceed with this problem. I have come across sequence-to-sequence model but not sequence to vector. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify from my sample, the custom LSTM layer can create identify vectors or the dyadic result. as a previous question.

Sample: Simply LSTM layer, training will fill variance and bias values.

```
import tensorflow as tf


class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        min_size_init = tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=10, maxval=10, seed=None)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
                        self.num_outputs],
                        initializer = min_size_init,
                        trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)
        
start = 3
limit = 9
delta = 3
        
# Create DATA
sample_1 = tf.range(start, limit, delta)
sample_1 = tf.cast( sample_1, dtype=tf.float32 )


start = 4
limit = 12
delta = 4

# Create DATA
sample_2 = tf.range(start, limit, delta)
sample_2 = tf.cast( sample_2, dtype=tf.float32 )


start = 5
limit = 13
delta = 4

# Create DATA
sample_3 = tf.range(start, limit, delta)
sample_3 = tf.cast( sample_2, dtype=tf.float32 )


# Multiply
sample_1 = tf.constant( sample_1, shape=( 1, 2 ) )
sample_2 = tf.constant( sample_2, shape=( 1, 2 ) )
sample_3 = tf.constant( sample_3, shape=( 1, 2 ) )
layer = MyDenseLayer(4)

data = layer(sample_1)
print( data )
data = layer(sample_2)
print( data )
data = layer(sample_3)
print( data )
```

Result: Two types of identities, training networks to have a bias against new input. Different can be seen in contrast when they are equally mind banners.

```
tf.Tensor([[90. 90. 90. 90.]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[120. 120. 120. 120.]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[120. 120. 120. 120.]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)

tf.Tensor([[90. 90. 90. 90.]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[120. 120. 120. 120.]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)

tf.Tensor([[120. 120. 120. 120.]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[120. 120. 120. 120.]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
```